# selenium with ng-hide wont let me click and gives visibility error

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

So I have 2 buttons, one appears on pc browser and one on a mobile browser, and I am trying to click one.

```
<button class="A otherclasses" ng-hide="isMobile">Button A</button>
<button class="B otherclasses ng-hide" ng-hide="!isMobile">Button B</button>
```

When I try to grab A the one that is showing on pc browser I get this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible
```

I grab A using this code:

> IWebElement target =
>   _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[ng-hide=\"isMobile\"]"));
>   Thread.Sleep(500);
>   target.Click();

I also tried grabbing it by By.ClassName() and still no luck
The test is in Visual Studio C#.
The driver is chrome.
I am trying to avoid to reference the text 'Button A' since it changes based on language.
I've been googling and fumbling around and I cannot grab A even though I can see it visually.

Comment: have you tried javascript executor ?

Comment: I tried variations of it but I couldn't get it working, it's possible I am not using the right parameters since most examples are for style="display:none"

Comment: have you tried xpath `//button[text()='Button A']`

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the text part? since the text changes based on language.

Comment: And I am still getting the not visible error with:

_driver.FindElement(
              By.XPath(
                "//button[text()='Button A']"
              )
            ).Click();

Comment: Are you sure that button A is the button which is visible and not Button A? I can think of nothing else. Sry :(

Comment: No capitalization errors
I tried using it on Button B to see if it's somehow magically the visible one. But no luck. 
Maybe I can ask our web guys to make this more selenium friendly. Thank you for your input!

Comment: I use selenium with java. I write javascriptexecutor as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);`. See if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button:not(.ng-hide)")).Click();
```